# Getting an error message when trying to open an excel file by double click

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

When I try to open an excel file by double click, I get the following error message:

> There was a problem sending the command to the program

After nothing helped, I removed and made a new installation of Microsoft office but it also didn't help.
I get the message from my account. The problem does not occur if I do it from an Administrator's account. 
So, I made my account an Administrator account. But it also didn't help.

Some comments:
I need to open and close lots of excels in a short time so I need this option to by working.
I also need to work with my Dropbox.
Also, it worked properly until a few days when stopped working.
no changes were deliberately done.. maybe some updates I am not aware off..

Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I get the message from my account. The problem does not occur when I do it from Administrators account.*

Make a new, test Windows User Account (User Account area depends on operating system).  Log into the new Windows Account and test Excel.

If Excel opens in the new Windows Account as well as Administrators, then you have a damaged Windows Profile and need to back up the data in it and make a new Windows Profile

Comment: I actually helped. I should Have thought about it myself I guess.. Thanks!